# Can you find the parent of the soup in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with beautiful soup in python, and I am working on a project that retrieves my school schedule. It's a badly written website. It is a HTML table, with every cell containing another table. inside that table, there is data. there are no id's or classes.

I've managed to get a list of all the tables I need, but there is one single value (rowspan) in the parent of the tables that I can't access, but I still need.

Is it possible to check out the parents of the soup when you do actually have the complete source laying around?

page:

```
<td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr><td>*data is here*</td></tr>
```

(my soup object is made of the HTML, starting at the table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a tags parent by calling the [`.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent) attribute.

```
...
print(soup.find('table').parent)
```

---

Edit: Try using the [`find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) method:

```
>>> html = """
... <td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center">
...     <table>
...         <tr><td>*data is here*</td></tr>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>>
>>> for tag in soup.find_all("table"):
...     print(tag.find_previous("td")["rowspan"])
...
4
>>>
```

Comment: Basically i am trying to create an easy restfulAPI out of the data. I got a list of every cell, and i made a couple functions that remove unnesesairy or empty cells, and retrieve information that is needed. But now i need the rowspan, as the cells go crazy when the rowspan is more then 2